# Making a non-thread menu - SurfaceView Android App

Tags: android, exception, null, drawing, surfaceview

I wrote a game and I'm trying to make it better and get rid of the bugs, and I have both the menu and the game state itself relying on a thread, but for menu I locked drawing so that it drawes each screen only once. My phone overheats on menu so I wanted to create the thread in the game state only, and make the menu independent from the thread, for example redrawing on touch.

I know how to do all of that and its pretty simple but I'm getting strange bugs, null pointer exceptions for my bitmaps that work flawlessly when the thread is on.

I have a onDraw(Canvas c) function where I have all written what to draw on each state(like menu or game state)

In the thread it looks like this(just the drawing part)

```
    c = null;
    c = holder.lockCanvas();
    synchronized(holder){
    onDraw(c);
    }
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Now I have written a simple method to call in order to draw in the menu

```
private void reDraw(){
menuCanvas = null;
menuCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
synchronized(holder){
onDraw(menuCanvas);}
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(menuCanvas);
}
```

And in onSizeChanged method
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
while (bmpBackground==null){
if (screenW>500){
bmploader = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bg_planet,options);
bmpBackground = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmploader, screenW, screenW, true);
if (bmploader!=null){
bmploader.recycle();
bmploader = null;
}
}
else{
bmploader =     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bg_planet_small,options);
            bmpBackground = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmploader, screenW, screenW, true);
            if (bmploader!=null){
                bmploader.recycle();
                bmploader = null;
            }
        }
        }
        loadMusic();
        loadBitmaps();
        loadShip();
        changeState(states.TITLE);
        reDraw();
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }
```

It pretty much tells me that bmpBackground is a null and throws a bug. And before I was just changing to title state and it was drawing normally(using the thread drawing);

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes/often, onSizeChanged gets called a number of times in succession, the first time with a width and height of w=0 and h=0.

The best thing to do is

a) add a check to see if width=0 and if so do nothing (it'll call this again with the proper dimensions; you also don't need to add a check for height=0, because either w and h will be 0 or they will be >0 and your call to bitmap creation will run without an error)

b)override the onSurfaceChanged of your surfaceview instead of onSizeChanged and do the recalculation/creation of your bitmaps then.